# According to advaitins, which brahma sutra says that the world is mithya?

Tags: philosophy, advaita, brahma-sutras

Advaitins believe that the world is mithya. There are advaita commentaries on the brahmasutras, most notably by Shankara himself. So according to advaitins, which brahmasutra or sutras say that the world is mithya?

EDIT: Replying to comments. According to the advaita school, the brahmasutras DO teach advaita alone. So it is reasonable to ask which brahmasutra teaches that the world is mithya. Secondly, a question about where brahmasutras teach that the world is satya, is irrelevant here. If someone wants to know this, they should post it as a separate question.

Comment: 'Mithya' was a word with special connotation used in Advaitavada.Btahma-Sutra is NOT a text that is solely related to Advaitavada.But can I ask: Which Brahma-Sutra says that the world is 'SAT' ?

Comment: Many Advaitin texts do so .... also the word "Mithya" is used terminologically in the Advaita texts ...

Comment: Please clarify what do you understand by 'Mithya'. Its not an English word and u r writing in English.

Comment: According to advaita, the chandogya upanishad teachings about gold and ornaments, pots and clay etc.  teach that the world is mithya. Dont remember if Shankara pulls out any one brahmasutra as teaching the mithyatva of the world.